# Track highest number in a cell over a series of recalculations

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

How do I keep track of the highest number that was in a cell in Google Sheets?

I'm running random numbers through a cell and I would like to track the highest number reached. Specifically, I am trying to count the number of matches between two random columns. I'd like to keep track of the highest number of matches between sheet refreshes. I have a button that I click to force recalculation on the page.

Comment: Are they really random numbers in the sense that you put `=rand()` into that cell? Or are they imported from some data source, or entered manually?

Comment: Are you tracking the value or the specific cell that the highest number is in?

Comment: I am trying to count the number of matches between two random columns. I'd like to keep track of the highest number of matches between sheet refreshes. I have a button that I click to force recalculation on the page.

Comment: @NathanS.Please edit that information into the question when you have a chance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep track of running maximum of the content of some cell, one needs a [script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) that runs every time the cell changes value. Such a script could be triggered by the same button you are using to force recalculation, although a delay (`Utilities.sleep(1000)`, time in milliseconds) may be necessary to make sure the recalculation runs before this script. Or, if recalculation was caused by an edit to the sheet, the function could be simply named [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) to run on every edit.

In this example, B1 is used to record the maximum of values that were placed in A1.

```
function recordMax() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B1");
  var values = range.getValues()[0];
  range.setValues([[values[0], Math.max(values[0], values[1])]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current relevant value in A1, A2 will retain the all-time highest value of A1 with this formula:

```
=max(A1,A2)
```

provided File > Spreadsheet settings..., Calculation has Iterative calculation set to `On` with Max. number of iterations set to `1`.

Answer (score -1):

In a cell of your choosing enter the formula:

> =max(**A1:A7**)

Where **A1:A7** are the cells of interest.


A1:A7 interprets as cells A1 through A7, in a column.

A1, A2, C1, C2 interprets each cell is looked at indiviually.

A1:A7, B1, C1:C3 or any combination.

> =max(A1:A7, B1, C2, D1:D20)

Comment: Correct but irrelevant.

Comment: @soup It's the best possible solution. You can't perform a VB to track past data. What solution do you propose?